# RegEx matching for G+ Profile URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to match just the user id or vanity part of the URI for Google+ accounts. I am using GAS (Google Script Engine) which I've loaded [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#usage-examples) to help match Unicode characters.

So far I have this: `((https?://)?(plus\.)?google\.com/)?(.*/)?([a-zA-Z0-9._]*)($|\?.*)` which you can see the [regex tests (external site)](http://fiddle.re/1b7qz) still don't just match the right parts.

I've tried using `\p{L}` inside of `[a-zA-Z0-9._]` but no luck with that. Also, I end up with an extra forward slash at the end of the profile name when it does match.

**UPDATE #1:** I am trying to fix some G+ URL in a spreadsheet copied from a Google Form. The links are not all the same and the most simplest profile link is "https://plus.google.com/" + user id OR vanity name.

**UPDATE #2:** So far I have `([+]\w+|[0-9]{21})(?:\/)?(?:\w+)?$` with uses [@demrks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291916/demrks) simplified version of [@guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314)'s response. However, two problems:

1) Google Vanity URLs can have unicode in them. Example: `https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JoseManuelGarcía_ertatto` which fails. I have tried to use \p{L} but can't seem to get it right.

2) GAS doesn't seem to like it event though [regex tests](http://fiddle.re/1b7qz) works on this site. =(

**UPDATE #3:** It seems GAS just hates using `\w` so I've had to expand it. So I have this so far:

```
/([+][A-Za-z0-9-_]+|[0-9]{21})(?:\/)?(?:[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)?$/
```

This matches even with "/about" or "/posts" at end of the URL. However still doesn't match UNICODE. =( I am still working on that.

**UPDATE #4:** So this seems to work:
    `/([+][\\w-_\\p{L}]+|[\\d]{21})(?:\/)?(?:[\\w-_]+)?$/`

Looks like I needed to do double backslashes in side of the character classes. So this seems to work so far. Not sure if there is shorter way to use this however.

Comment: Does all the vanity names and user id that u r using start with a + ?

Comment: all the vanity url start with "+" but all the user id's don't. so it's more of a [+]? condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should match both IDs and usernames (with unicode characters):

```
/\+[^/]+|\d{21}/
```

http://regexr.com/39ds0

**Explanation:** As an alternative to `\w` (which doesn't match unicode characters) I used a negation group `[^/]` (matches anything but "/").

Comment: Why do you use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`? Btw, that works now. One day I'll get better at these! ... ha!

Comment: @flamusdiu Not sure, why I did this :) I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Edit, updated

Try (v4)

```
document.URL.match(/\++\w+.*|\d+\d|\/+\w+$/).toString()
.replace(/\/+|posts|about|photos|videos|plusones|reviews/g, "")
```

e.g.,

```
var urls = ["https://plus.google.com/+google/posts"
            , "https://plus.google.com/+google/about"
            , "https://plus.google.com/+google/photos"
            , "https://plus.google.com/+google/videos"
            , "https://plus.google.com/+google/plusones"
            , "https://plus.google.com/+google/reviews"
            , "https://plus.google.com/communities/104645458102703754878"
            , "https://plus.google.com/u/0/LONGIDHERE"
            , "https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JoseManuelGarcía_ertatto"];
var _urls = [];

urls.forEach(function(item) {
  _urls.push(item.match(/\++\w+.*|\d+\d|\/+\w+$/).toString()
            .replace(/\/+|posts|about|photos|videos|plusones|reviews/g, ""));

});

_urls.forEach(function(id) {
    var _id = document.createElement("div");
    _id.innerHTML = id;
    document.body.appendChild(_id)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/o4kvftwh/

Comment: yeah, I have a list of profile URLs in a spreadsheet and I need to extract either the vanity name (+<some profile name>) or the user id (which happens to be a 21 digit number.

Comment: @flamusdiu I think you can modify guest273114 regex a bit... Something like that should work: `\++\w+|[0-9]{21}`

Comment: I'm dumb. haha .. I see you are just matching on the first "+" then grabbing the rest of it. I was doing the hard way. =\

Comment: Some reason GAS doesn't like the \++ to escape the "+". I keep having to do `[+]+` instead.

Comment: Updated question with extra info now. =) Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @demrks Do you konw why `https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JackArnold7/posts` that doesn't match? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @flamusdiu For me both [/\++\w+|\d+\d|\/+\w+$/](http://regexr.com/39dr5) and [\++\w+|\[0-9\]{21}](http://www.regexr.com/39dr8) work as expected for your test string.

Comment: @demrks Yeah, I see that ... let me switch out -- it's something to do with GAS. How would you check for Unicode character as well as `\w`?

Comment: @demrks whoops. Space at the end in the cell was preventing the match ... haha =\

Comment: @flamusdiu Wrote my solution below that should also match unicode characters.

Comment: Nice update. I think @demrks is still shorter with his interesting use of the neg in it. It's always good to see different ways to get to the same thing. =)

Answer (score 0):

Following a possible solution:

```
(?:\+)(\w+)|(?:\/)(\w+)$
```

Explanation:

- 1st Alternative: `(?:\+)(\w+)`

  `(?:\+)` Non-capturing group: `\+` matches the character `+` literally. Capturing group `(\w+)`: `\w+` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Quantifier: Between one and unlimited
  times.
- 2nd Alternative: `(?:\/)(\w+)$`. `(?:\/)` Non-capturing group. `\/` matches the character `/` literally. Capturing group `(\w+)`. `\w+` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times. `$` assert position at end of the string.

Hope it useful!

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to work:
`/([+][\\w-_\\p{L}]+|[\\d]{21})(?:\/)?(?:[\\w-_]+)?$/`

Looks like I needed to do double backslashes in side of the character classes. So this seems to work so far. Not sure if there is shorter way to use this however.